# Making changes to Google+ SignIn using API

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

I am using Google Android API for integrating Google SignIn in my app. I am able to login successfully, but the API prompts dialog to choose an account even if one account is registered with the account manager.

I want to how we can change this. I have seen this things being implemented in many apps in App Store but I am not able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: cant help with android but look for something like approval_prompt its what normally pops that window up.

Comment: Is there any way to skip that or do that manually?